# Symmetric matrix result: $A^{T} + A = S$

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I came across this question in a paper, there are no solutions.

> Let $S \in \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix,
>   having the property that $v^{t}Sv > 0$,
>   $v\in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ \mathbf{0} \}$.
>
> Suppose $A \in \text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $A^{T} + A = S$.
>
> Prove that the null space of $A$ is $\{ \mathbf{0} \}$.

---

I think of a few ways to do this, but I'm not sure. For example we can use a $3\times3$ matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix} 
+ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}^T 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix} 
+ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & d & g \\
b & e & h \\
c & f & i
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
2a & b+d & c+g \\
b+d & 2e & f+h \\
c+g & f+h & 2i
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

However, this does not look very elegant. Is there a result regarding symmetric matrices I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $v \neq 0, \;Av = 0$ then $$v^T Sv = v^T(A + A^T)v = v^TAv + v^TA^Tv = 0 + 0=0$$

Which contradicts your condition (which is called positive definiteness).

Comment: Right, I missed this fact that if $v$ cannot be a zero vector then $v^{T}A^{T} = 0$ holds as well. Thank you.

Comment: @GambitZone You're welcome, and welcome to stack exchange!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Assume the null space of $A$ is not $\left\{0\right\}$. Therefore there exists $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $Av=0$ and as a consequence $v^{t}A^{t}=0$ as well. Can you calculate $v^{t}Sv$?